# Sometimes audio doesn't play with Android AudioManager Audio Focus

Tags: android, audio

I've got a bit of an odd bug at the moment. I'm using the AudioManager to play a looping clip, but first requesting audio focus:

```
private void startPlayer(Sound sound) {

    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        initMediaPlayer(sound);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not play audio at the moment...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In my stop() method I'm running:

```
....  
if (player != null) {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }

    player.reset();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
....
```

...and in my start method I initialise the player using:

```
...
player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), lookupSoundId(sound));
player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
player.setLooping(true);
player.start();
...
```

I've implemented an onAudioFocusChange method which stops the audio if something else plays audio. This all works perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            if (player == null) {
                initMediaPlayer(currentSound);
            } else {
                if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                    play(); // this method updates the UI and starts the player
                }
            }
            player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            Log.d("onAudioFocusChange", "AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
            if ((player != null) && (player.isPlaying())) {
                stop(); // this method updates the UI and stops the player
            }
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            Log.d("onAudioFocusChange", "AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
            if ((player != null) && (player.isPlaying())) {
                player.pause();
            }
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            Log.d("onAudioFocusChange", "AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
            if ((player != null) && (player.isPlaying())) {
                player.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

My issue is described as a series of steps, as it's a bit weird and it's running on a Nexus 5 with Android L developer preview (LPV79) installed:

1. Press play in my app and the loop starts playing
2. Press pause in my app and the loop stops
3. Repeat this ad infinitum and all is well
4. Press play in my app then open Google Music Player and press play—my app stops playing and music starts to play
5. Press pause in Google Music Player
6. Return to my app
7. Press play in my app and the loop starts playing
8. Press pause in my app and the loop stops
9. Press play in my app and the UI updates as if the audio is playing but no audio is playing
10. Press pause in my app then play then pause then play etc but no audio will play, although the UI is updating and the code seems to all be running and with no errors/warnings
11. EITHER: Terminate Google Music Player app then press play in my app and the loop starts playing
12. OR: wait for 5 minutes then press play in my app and the loop starts playing

Also, at the end of my stop() method, I'm calling audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(...); to say I don't need audio focus at the moment.

The annoying thing is that when I try to debug this and put breakpoints in, the audio plays fine. I'm not really sure what's causing it. :/